# Inserting values Into a Application through Jmeter

Tags: session, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am working on Jmeter and Testopia.I have recorded a test case scenario where user enters values such as plan Id,Category,Priority using Jmeter.I want to pass values to these fields from CSV file and I am trying to do this through jmeter.In Validate Tree result I am able to see the values beign passed.But when I open the Testopia Test Plan the values are not visible.My question is whether it is possible to insert value into any application through Jmeter.
Please Help

Comment: *it is possible to insert value into any application through Jmeter.* It is possible to do anything that you can do through a browser.

Comment: I identified the problem is with the session Id but the scenario is that jmeter is not record the session Id.Is there any way for passing the session id if it is not recorded by jmeter

Comment: session ID is usually handled in cookies and is inserted into request headers. Take a look at JMeter HTTP cookie manager.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use regular expression extractor to catch the session ID in one of your previously requests and then add it as a parameter. (I can't post it as a comment)